# How to create different header names for api calls in swagger?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger

I am using the django restfull framwework with swagger.

And swagger works fine. But I try to create different headers for the api calls. Because the current situation is that it is just one long list with header name api.

But I have these api call names:

> PUT /api/accounts/me/ PATCH /api/accounts/me/ POST
> /api/accounts/token/ GET /api/animals/ POST /api/animals/ GET
> /api/animals/{id}/

So api/accounts and api/animals.

And I try to create for each api/... seperate header name. Like:

Accounts:
api/accounts/me
api/accounts/token

Animals:
api/animals
api/animals/{id}, etc

So I the url.py file in the main app looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
   path('api/', include('DierenWelzijnAdmin.urls')),
         
         
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('schema/', get_schema_view()),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path('api/docs', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-docs'),
    path('api/accounts/',include('accounts.urls') )
    
]
```

and I have two seperate apps: Accounts and DierenWelZijnAdmin:

urls Accounts:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', views.CreateUserView.as_view(), name='create'),
    path('logout/',views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),    
    path('token/', views.CreateTokenView.as_view(), name='token'),
    path('me/', views. ManageUserView.as_view(), name='me'),    
    path('login/', obtain_auth_token, name='login' )
]
```

and urls DierenWelZijnAdmin:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))   
]
```

And serializer of DierenWelZijnAdmin looks:

```
class AnimalViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, permissions.BasePermission):
   
    queryset = Animal.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = AnimalSerializer    
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 


class CategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, permissions.BasePermission):
    

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'action') and self.action == 'main_groups':
            return MainGroupSerializer
        return CategorySerializer   
    

    queryset1 = Category.objects.all().order_by('name')
    queryset = CategorySerializer.eager_load(queryset1)
    serializer_class = get_serializer_class(super)

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated] 

    @action(methods=['get'], detail=False)
    def main_groups(self, request):
       
        main_groups = Category.objects.filter(category_id__isnull=True)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(main_groups, many=True)
      
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Question: how to create sepererate headers for api url?